# Automatic fitting of normalization constant as a parameter in noise contrastive estimation

Tags: machine-learning, maximum-likelihood, optimization, density-function, unsupervised-learning

In the paper on [Noise Contrastive Estimation](http://proceedings.mlr.press/v9/gutmann10a/gutmann10a.pdf), the authors define a parameterized density function $p_m^0\left(x;\alpha\right)$ to estimate the unnormalized PDF of the data, and then further define a function  $p_m\left(x;\theta\right) =  ln\left(p_m^0\left(x;\alpha\right)\right) + C$, where $C$ is the logarithm of the normalization constant.

Then, under the assumption a noise PDF $p_n\left(x\right)$ over the support of x is employed to generate contrastive samples, they go on to define a cost function matching typical logistic regression (cross entropy) under a nonlinear logistic regression model with the posterior probability $P(data;\theta) = h(x,\theta)$ where $h(x,\theta)$ is a logistic function with the argument of the exponential function being $ln\left(p_m(x;\theta)\right) - ln\left(p_n(x)\right)$

This is all fine and good -- and they go on to discuss associated theorems and show resulting comparisons to MLE and contrastive divergence, etc.  HOWEVER, they only claim [several times] that the $C$ parameter will just automatically be optimized such that it normalizes $p_m^0\left(x;\alpha\right)$ to integrate to 1.  Literally from the article "With our objective
function, no such constraints are necessary. The
maximizing pdf is found to have unit integral automatically.
".

I don't see a proof of this (and it's not obvious to me that it's true).  The have a starred note for the following theorem that states "proofs are omitted due to a lack of space":

In Theorem 1 of their paper, they make this claim that "$J$" (the likelihood) attains a maximum when $p_m\left(x;\theta\right) = p_d$ (when the model equals the actual pdf of the data)

I'm not seeing how this is going to be true *(i.e., that C will normalize $p_m^0\left(x;\alpha\right)$)* as the cost function stands defined.

Comment: This was first proposed by Charlie Geyer in 1992 in an unpublished technical report.

Comment: The proofs of the theorems can be found in the [journal version](http://www.jmlr.org/papers/volume13/gutmann12a/gutmann12a.pdf) of the paper. I'm also not very clear on why the normalization constant falls out of the optimization process, but I assume it's a consequence of theorem 1: if the estimated distribution $p_m$ converges to the true distribution $p_d$ then $p_m$ should be normalized as data distribution $p_d$ is normalized by definition.